# Looping though Dataframes Doesnt feel right

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey there guys  I have come to Python via Excel VBA as a way of dealing with large data sets that I'm using.

I have several datasets that is depth based and I need to "populate up" some data sets to match the finest data resolution actual (for when I get to image clustering ) .  The images are getting me data on 0.01mm  while some of my measured  dataset are on samples that are about 40mm in  size. To scale the measured data from a point im using the code below.

I get the feeling I'm missing the point with Dataframes and falling back on my VBA (bad??) habits

The dataset I'm testing this on is about 50,000 rows and the `size` variable is set at 200 (ie 200 x .1mm each way for 40mm total).

At some stage in the future ill be doing this with IR image array style data for each of `a` `b` `c` sets below.

I can see that because of the iteration this is currently taking a lit of time.  Hoping there is a brain out there that can see though my fumbling code

```
def new_depth(df, size):
    x=0
    for i in df['Depth']:
        x=+1
        measured_data = df.iloc[x, :]
        for y in range(size):
            if y!=0:
                added_p = i+y
                added_n = i-y
                measured_data["Depth"] = added_p
                df.loc[len(df)] = measured_data
                measured_data["Depth"] = added_n
                df.loc[len(df)]=measured_data
```

Ignoring the scale of things the general concept is:

Initial df

```
Depth  | Item1 | Item 2 | Item3 
-----  |-------|--------|------
10.01  |   a   |   b    |   c
10.02  |   d   |   e    |   f
10.03  |   h   |   i    |   j
```

New df

```
Depth    | Item1 | Item 2 | Item3 
-----    |-------|--------|------
etc
10.008   |   a   |   b    |   c
10.009   |   a   |   b    |   c
**10.010   |   a   |   b    |   c**
10.011   |   a   |   b    |   c
10.012   |   a   |   b    |   c
etc
---------------------------------
etc
10.018   |   d   |   e    |   f
10.019   |   d   |   e    |   f
**10.020   |   d   |   e    |   f**
10.021   |   d   |   e    |   f
10.022   |   d   |   e    |   f
etc
```

Comment: Can you explain what your `new_depth` function is supposed to achieve? Best if you could provide an example dataframe as input and then the expected output from applying the method to that dataframe.

Comment: @Metropolis,  I've restated the question above, hopefully this explains it a little better,  I'm getting  used to getting information into stack overflow.  I've been getting answers for years from here  but this is my first post!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
step=0.001
df2 = df.reindex(pd.Float64Index(np.arange(df.index[0], df.index[-1]+step, step=step).round(3))).ffill()
```

This uses 'Depth' as index

## Range

`np.arange(df.index[0], df.index[-1]+step, step=step).round(3)` makes a [range](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange)

```
array([ 10.01 ,  10.011,  10.012,  10.013,  10.014,  10.015,  10.016,
        10.017,  10.018,  10.019,  10.02 ,  10.021,  10.022,  10.023,
        10.024,  10.025,  10.026,  10.027,  10.028,  10.029,  10.03 ])
```

The `df.index[-1]+step` is to make sure the last index is included. The `.round(3)` is to prevent rounding errors. Floating point comparison is a tricky thing.

## Index

The `pd.Float64Index(<range>)` makes the index. It also works without this step, but makes it more explicit.

## Reindex

The `df.reindex(<index>)` sets this created index as the new index for the `DataFrame`, and tries to find older entries in `df` that match this index. It fills the other rows with `NaN`

```
    Item1   Item 2  Item3
Depth           
10.010  a   b   c
10.011  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.012  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.013  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.014  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.015  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.016  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.017  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.018  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.019  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.020  d   e   f
10.021  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.022  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.023  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.024  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.025  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.026  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.027  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.028  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.029  NaN     NaN     NaN
10.030  h   i   j
```

## ffil

the `.ffil()` fills empty items with the item from the preceding row. If you only need to fill maximum 5 items you can use `.ffil(limit=5)`. `ffill` is a synonym for [`.fillna(method='ffill)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

Comment: Well that helps thanks @Mateen Fabre,  I have been trying to get the depth as an index but kept crapping out,  the flaot64 line will help me with some other work I have coming up.  ffill also useful to have in the toolbox

Comment: Ok so it look like the reindex is not quite as I expected it from the code. the index column is now just showing up is 0.01, 0.02 etc etc   I would have though `df.index[-1]+step` would make it 10.001 etc   I might be missing something so will keep tinkering  it is almost as if it is creating a new index of zero value and adding the step to that

Comment: I divided the explanation for the answer up to make it more clear. If there are still mysteries, don't hesitate to ask

Comment: thanks @Maarten Fabre,  the explanation is great, let me play with it when I get a chance, but understanding the individual steps  will make life easier for me in the future

Comment: worked through my data and its all good now.  appreciate the help Marteen.